# Is it best practice to use spring jpa findall for complex relation mappings

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Is it good practice to use spring jpa findAll or use a select query as findAll is taking much time due to complexity of the relationship that too eager fetch....

Pls help

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not a good practice to set the `Eager` fetch directly in the entities on the `Many` side of a relationship unless those related entities are tightly coupled and you know you won't select one without the other.

You should use a custom select query to specify join fetch where you actually need it.

N.b. for the `OneToOne` and `ManyToOne` relationship the default is already `Eager`

Comment: Yes it is tightly coupled that is the reason why i use eager... If  i use custom  how will i bind values to the class expecially how will i bind the one to many relation collection....

Comment: I'm not understanding your requirment... can you add an example of what you tried?